# Show IP and connection info in Minimalistic Text

Tags: app-widgets, customization

is it possible to show the phone IP and/or connection info using the Minimalistic Text widget ?

I did not find any field of this kind in the customization menu, but I do know that is possible to supply external variables via other programs: for instance, I use Llama to print my location on the widget.

Maybe there are some programs that can do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the new and current Minimalistic Text version, it is possible to print the Wifi IP  and SSID information if you donate to the developer.